# disable and enable buttons vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to disable the "OK" button when the validateAdd form loads, then enable the "OK" button when the user input some text in the textboxes.

Here is my code for disable and enable button.

```
Private Sub validateAdd_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If txtaddlname.Text = String.Empty AndAlso txtaddfname.Text = String.Empty AndAlso txtaddmid.Text = String.Empty Then
        btnaddOk.Enabled = False
    Else
        btnaddOk.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is my validateAdd Form with empty textbox:
[image]

the button is already disabled but when i tried putting some text in it, the button is still disabled.
[image]

Comment: the load event happens once only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead put all that code in the `TextChanged` event of the three textboxes:

```
Private Sub fields_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtaddlname.TextChanged, txtaddfname.TextChanged, txtaddmid.TextChanged
    If txtaddlname.Text = String.Empty AndAlso txtaddfname.Text = String.Empty AndAlso txtaddmid.Text = String.Empty Then
        btnaddOk.Enabled = False
    Else
        btnaddOk.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Since the `Loaded` event of a `Form` occurs only once. Hope it helps :)

Comment: you beat me to it.

Comment: @codeMonger123 never mind, happens. compensation coming in a minute :)

Comment: @Jinx Glad I could help :) Cheers!